# Form getting submitted when hit enter key after selecting option from multi select lookup in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have written below code to avoid form submission when we select the option from multiselect lookup using enter key. The below code is working fine in case of IE8 and IE9 but in Firefox the below code is not working and form is getting submitted.

```
element.on("keydown",function( event ){
                        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            element.val(newselectedvalue);
                            self.focus(); 
                            return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.

I ended up adding a class on the inputs that provide the multiselect lookup.
Just like this answer:
[Disabling enter key for selected submit buttons within a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830075/disabling-enter-key-for-selected-submit-buttons-within-a-form/9830430#9830430)